# Build .NET Standard Library 1.4 using .NET Framework 4.6.1 without visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, msbuild, .net-4.6.1

We try building .NET Standard Library 1.4 Project using .NET Framework 4.6.1 using Command prompt without visual studio in windows server 2012 RC2 for Automation purpose.

I have installed the following on the Server,

```
.Net Framework 4.6.1
.Net Framework 4.6.1 Targeting pack
Microsoft Build Tools 2015
```

This .NET Standard Library Project say ProjectA was referenced with two other .NET standard Library Project ProjectB and ProjectC.

Keeping ProjectA as Startup Project

When I try to compile the ProjectA after **dotnet restore** using **dotnet build** cmd, I am getting the following error,

```
C:\Document\ProjectA>dotnet build

Project ProjectA (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4) will be compiled because 
expected outputs are missing

Compiling ProjectA for .NETStandard,Version=v1.4
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe compile-csc 
@C:\Document\ProjectA\obj\Debug\netstandard1.4\dotnet-compile.rsp returned 
Exit Code 1

C:\Document\ProjectA\Sample.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 
'ProjectB' does not exist in the namespace 'XYZ' (are you missing an 
 assembly reference?)

C:\Document\ProjectA\Sample.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 
'ProjectC' does not exist in the namespace 'XYZ' (are you missing an 
 assembly reference?)

Compilation failed.
0 Warning(s)
2 Error(s)
```

Please help me to compile the solution from command prompt.
Sample Code:

```
using XYZ.ProjectB;
using XYZ.ProjectC;
using System;


namespace XYZ.ProjectA
{
    public class Sample : ISample
    {
        public Void GetMessage()
        {
            var s=XYZ.ProjectB.GetList();
            Console.Write("");      
        }
    }
}
```

Both ProjectB and Project C are also .Netstandard Lib

Comment: `The type or namespace name 'ProjectB' does not exist in the namespace 'XYZ'` This says it all!, The projects dont have the same root namespace!

Comment: Thank you for your response Suraj. It exists in the same namespace..It compile and executes properly in visual studio..But it throws error when i compile with the help of command prompt.

Comment: You will need to provide code in `ABC.cs`

Comment: Included in the Question

Comment: if it builds in VS but not in command line I'd be looking at other factors.
What if you run in administration mode?

Comment: are you using visual studio to build it on the same machine that you are trying to build it in command line?
If these are two different machines, Maybe look at the latest .Net Core Tools for the server?

Comment: No different machine. I build it with visual studio at local and command prompt at server. Also all .net core tools were installed same for both local and server.

Comment: And Joe, I haven't tried as admin. let me check with this and let you know.

Comment: Where is the root XYZ namespace defined? something like `namespace XYZ{ ....}` ?

Comment: Is this a `project.json` based .net standard libarary? those aren't supported by the build tools and need the full VS + web tools installation.

Comment: Thanks for your response martin. yes it is project.json based .net standard library project. First we are restoring the project.json library using dotnet restore command to generate project.json.lock. Then I tried building with dotnet build. Martin what about your opinion using MSBuild command.

Comment: Any reason you're still using project.json? I'd strongly advise you to update to final 1.0 tooling. It'll make everything *much* simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the above case by building the project using **MSBuild**

As I mentioned earlier that after the following framework installed in server,

```
 1. .Net Framework 4.6.1 
 2. .Net Framework 4.6.1 Targeting pack
 3. Microsoft Build Tools 201
```

And I'm attempting to build portable projects targeting .NET Standard from server where the Visual Studio was not installed, I managed to copy the following files and folder from a machine that does have Visual Studio installed to my build server.

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Portable\v14.0
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable
3. C:\Program Files (x86)\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable
4. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet

And installed `Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6`  on the server.

Then called the version of MsBuild to build your solution from,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe MySolution.sln
```

The above steps helped me to build the .NET Standard Libarary Project without installing Visual Studio on the build Server.

I hope the above information helps someone !